# MongoDB - Updating only $ref from DBRef field type

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to update a field of multiple collection documents. The field is a **DBRef** and I just need to change the **$ref** field value.

One of the documents is like this:

> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50ab682bd3155502a75c7cf6"} , "codeId" : { "$ref"
>   : "version" , "$id" : { "$oid" : "511cb7d5696bdbaf4c85ebb1"}}}

The final result I want is this:

> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50ab682bd3155502a75c7cf6"} , "codeId" : { "$ref"
>   : "***code***" , "$id" : { "$oid" : "511cb7d5696bdbaf4c85ebb1"}}}

I've tried it like this:

```
db.collection.update(
   {}, 
   {$set:{"codeId":{$ref:"code"}}},
   false,
   true
);
```

The problem is that the **$id** is lost (set as null)

> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "50ab682bd3155502a75c7cf6"} , "codeId" : { "$ref"
>   : "***code***" , "$id" : { "$oid" : ***null***}}}

How do I keep the **$id**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation in order to update the nested document. Note that, whenever the dot notation is used, it should be put between quotes.

```
db.collection.update(
   {}, 
   { $set:{
       "codeId.$ref":"code"
     }
   },
   false,
   true
);
```

You can read more about [Database References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/).

Comment: But I don't want to explicitly define it because this is an update and the $id is already defined on the original document.

Comment: Note that this might not work due to the 
``The DBRef $ref field must be following by a $id field`` errors.