# MongoDB - Updated $ref value unable to query new value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've posted the following question which has been answered correctly:

[MongoDB - Updating only $ref from DBRef field type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057493/mongodb-updating-only-ref-from-dbref-field-type)

Despite of this when I execute the find method like this:

> { "codeId" : { "$ref" : "code" , "$id" : { "$oid" :
>   "4ff1c08c6ef25616ce21c4b6"}} }

The document isn't returned... Any idea why?

After the update the document is stored like this:

> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "5097ae1cd3159eb52d05574c"} , "codeId" : { "$ref"
>   : "code" , "$id" : { "$oid" : "4ff1c08c6ef25616ce21c4b6"}} }

By the way, using uMongo GUI, if I select the Update option over this stored document, and save it, without making any changes whatsoever, and then make the find query once again, the document is returned by the query...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a clearly one of those DBRef "tweaky" things...

As a temporary (but probably correct) fix, I managed to solve this problem executing this javascript procedure:

```
var cursor = db.menu.find( { "codeId.$ref" : "version" } );

while( cursor.hasNext() )
{
    var document = cursor.next();

    db.menu.update(
        document,
        { $set: {"codeId" : DBRef("code", document.codeId.$id) }},
        { upsert:  false, multi: true }
    );
}
```

Still, I won't consider this to be the best way to achieve what I want... Any other solution that involves less lines?